# A quick way to set all visible objects on a layer to non-rendered (camera icon off in 2.79)?

Tags: 3d-view, texture-baking, layers

I'd need a quick way to set the renderability (camera icon) off for all invisible hidden objects in a selected layer.

Basically I am trying to make an ao bake but I'd need to turn renderability off for all objects that are hidden. Due to the big size of the scene and big number of objects I don't want to do this manually. And I only need to do this for one layer. I don't want to adjust renderability for objects on other layers.

Other option would be to use the visibility for renderability (use the eye icon for the camera icon so to speak) and just ignore objects in the bake that are set hidden. Is that possible?

Comment: Read the second part of this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/hide-geometry-in-render

Comment: Thanks, perfect!